# How to minimize toolbar in Intellij 13

Tags: intellij-idea

How to move **build/run/debug** options like in this window.

It is in Mac, I'm not able to find a way in Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a little bit late but all you have to do is hide the toolbar ( **View** -> **Toolbar** ) and the minimized version will show on the right of your navigation bar